Does the mock hardware component "mock_components/GenericSystem" provided by ros2 control support the 'velocity' command interface?
When I change the command interface from 'position' to 'velocity' in Moveit2 tutorial (MoveIt Setup Assistant — MoveIt Documentation: Rolling documentation), I found the crux of the problem is the hardware component.
This is the details:
ros2 - How to correctly change the command interface of the panda robot arm from 'position' to 'velocity' in the Moveit2 website tutorial - Robotics Stack Exchange
Could someone provide an explanation of the hardware components "mock_components/GenericSystem"?
I can't find the configuration for changing the command interface.
Here is offcial document about "Mock Components":
Mock Components — ROS2_Control: Humble Apr 2024 documentation

You have to set calculate_dynamics parameter to calculate the position states from velocity commands
<hardware>
    <plugin>mock_components/GenericSystem</plugin>
    <param name="calculate_dynamics">true</param>
</hardware>

I saw now that this is missing in the documentation, I'll fix that soon.
